# How to countinue an task in when the app enters backgroudn in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, ios6

How can i run an task till its completion even if the app enters background while resigning the active state in iPhone (iOS).

Answer (score 4):

First We need to check either the device supports Multitasking or NOt ??

```
if([UIDevice currentDevice]respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)){

  //  If the device supports Multitasking we can run the task as :-

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;

    bgTask=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul), ^{
        for(double i=0; i<99999; i++)
            NSLog(@"Backgroudn quee");

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this the answer or are you adding to the question? Thanks

Comment: Its the answer which i figured out